# Creating a Bazaar branch from an offline SVN working copy?

Tags: svn, dvcs, bazaar, tortoisebzr

I'm doing some offline development on my SVN working copy. Since I won't have access to the SVN repository for a while, I wanted to use Bazaar as a helper version control to keep the intermediate commit history before I commit everything back to the SVN repository. Is this possible?

When I try to create a branch using TortoiseBZR from the SVN working copy, it wants to access the SVN repository, which is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just disable/uninstall bzr-svn plugin if you don't need to work with svn servers from bzr.

Or, in the command-line execute following command:

```
bzr --no-plugins init
```

It will create bzr branch in your directory, and after that bzr and TortoiseBzr won't try to open svn working copy.

But you probably still will have problems when running bzr commands from subfolders.
So, you can add all required files in your svn copy under bzr version control, then commit them:

```
bzr add
bzr commit -m initial
```

Now you can re-create this state of files in different (empty) directory with

```
bzr branch path/to/bzr/branch/in/svn/copy new/path
```

And do all work in `new/path`. When you'll be ready to update your svn working copy with latest committed revision from new/path then just push your changes back:

```
bzr push path/to/bzr/branch/in/svn/copy
```